# How do I set a stored procedure?

Tags: database

How can I process following query structure in drupal 7.

```
set @num := 0, @termid := 0;



SELECT  * FROM (SELECT tid,nid,created,
           @num:=IF(@termid = tid, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
           @termid:=tid AS termid .......
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Are you sure you need to achieve it that way? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I want to create store procedure via .install file.

Answer (score 1):

It has been **solved** using.

function  hook_install(){

db_query("CREATE PROCEDURE `xyz`()

BEGIN
    set @num := 0, @termid := 0; 
    ......................................");